# What's up with all the QR codes?

Tags: coinbase.com, spending

Just bought $5 of Bitcoins from CoinBase. How do I spend them? I gather it has something to do with QR codes. . . .

Answer (score 0):

don't worry -- they're there for convenience only.

Scanning the QR code helps reading either a public key (to verify) or your private key (to spend your bitcoins) into whatever application you are using to verify or spend from your balance respectively.

Copy-and-paste works as well, doing the same for you as those QR codes you see everywhere...